# Limit regex output to first occurance of special character in postgres (regexp_match)

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am applying following regex on a column with value

```
uniprotkb:P89903(protein(MI:0326), 349975 - Simian immunodeficiency virus - agm.tan-1)
```

```
^[^:]*:\s*[^()]+\(.*\(.*\),.*\-(.*)
```

to extract text after first '-'. The desired out is:

```
Simian immunodeficiency virus - agm.tan-1
```

However, my regex is matching the last occurence of '-'. How can I get the limit the output to first occurrence of '-'

Thanks

Comment: Try `^[^:]*:\s*[^()]+\([^()]*\([^()]*\),[^-]*-\s*([^)]*)`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
select REGEXP_MATCHES('uniprotkb:P89903(protein(MI:0326), 349975 - Simian immunodeficiency virus - agm.tan-1)', '^[^:]*:\s*[^()]+\([^()]*\([^()]*\),[^-]*-\s*([^)]*)')
```

See the [online PostgreSQL demo](https://rextester.com/ICCK54457). Output:

[image]

**NOTES**

- All `.*` are replaced with negated character classes to temper the pattern a bit so that the `.` could not match parentheses
- Last `.*` is turned into `[^)]*` to match right up to the  `)` excluding it.

A more lax pattern you may use here is to find `space`+`-`+`space` and match all chars other than `)` from there (i.e. `' - (.*)\)'` pattern):

```
select REGEXP_MATCHES('uniprotkb:P89903(protein(MI:0326), 349975 - Simian immunodeficiency virus - agm.tan-1)', ' - (.*)\)')
```

See [this online demo](https://rextester.com/AVF37700)